# ngxs: Store not initialized when injected

Tags: ngxs, angular14

I am using ngxs 3.7.5 with Angular 14

```js
// single slice 
@State<EnvironmentStateModel>({
  name: 'environment',
  defaults: {
    productionBuild: environment.production,
    internalPlatform: detectInternalPlatform(window.location.hostname, window.location.port),
    platform: detectPlattform(),
    appVersion: environment.appVersion   
  }
})
@Injectable()
export class EnvironmentState {
  
}
```

I am injecting the store into a HttpInterceptor

```js
export class MessageHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {


  constructor(private userService: UserService, private store: Store) {
    
    console.log('constructor', this.store.selectSnapshot((appState: AppState) => appState));
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
    console.log('intercept', this.store.selectSnapshot((appState: AppState) => appState));

    //...
  
  }

}
```

The console statement in the constructor shows `{}`, also the console statement in the first call to `intercept`. However consecutive calls to `intercept` show `{ environment: ... }` that is with the environment slice properly initialized. I expect the store to be properly initialized when using it the first time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found the problem: HttpInterceptor was called when loading i18n JSON resource files, this happens at a very early stage in Angular application start. I dont need store for these type of http requests and filter them out.

Answer (score 0):

When you include the `NgxsModule` in the import, the `EnvironmentState` should be passed to the `NgxsModule`'s `.forRoot()` function (if it's a root store), or `.forFeature()` function (if it's a lazy-loaded store).

You can find more details here:

- https://www.ngxs.io/getting-started/installation
- https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/lazy

Comment: I do this already. The environment slice does appear but too late.